# Is there any way I can try to save my Java question about getting a static nested class by name?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

(Full disclosure: This issue has already been discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56778027) and then it was suggested I post about this on MSO.)

I asked [Fastest way to get a static nested class by name using reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74966505/16217248) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fquTi.jpg)) about how to do a specific thing in Java. It was closed as a duplicate of several questions where 2 of which were workarounds to achieve what I described.

At first I tried changing my question to ask if there was a 'direct' way to do it without those workarounds? However my question was [left closed in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/34420346).

I then tried changing the question to ask for the fastest way to do what I was describing in case there was no more 'direct' way to do it. But it still remains closed and downvoted, and it eventually got automatically deleted before any reopen reviewers had time to either reopen it or leave it closed from review.

Is there anything I can do to save the question as my previous attempts to differentiate it from the duplicates have failed? Or should I just let it go? Can I have some advice for this particular question about what is missing from the question that I could add or change to make it reopen and undelete worthy?

Comment: How do you plan on defining "fastest"? That would be a very good place to start.

Comment: @Paulie_D Would execute most quickly on most Java virtual machines.

Comment: @user16217248 what is your motivation behind the question? are you actually running into a performance issue, or are you just curious about how the compiler optimizes the code?

Comment: @TonyArra Curious about how the compiler and/or runtime optimizes code.

Comment: "Fastest" can be ambiguous even with the context. What you're really looking for then is the "most performant method" or the "most efficient algorithm"; although it would depend heavily on your class hierarchy. Alternatively, you could run your own benchmarks and then ask why a particular method is more performant under certain conditions.

Comment: @TonyArra What definition of "fastest" is there other than "most performant"?

Comment: @SecurityHound Because I never really got around to it until now. And I never really got an answer. I was working on other, non-Java projects between now and then. And it's (almost) always better to try to improve your existing posts instead of making new ones.

Comment: @SecurityHound [Here is why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w90bW.png)

Comment: If I am not mistaken it did not receive downvotes until May even though it was asked in December, but the original downvoter retracted the downvote and the current -2 are new, so I'll never know by looking at the vote summaries.

Comment: "_2 of which were workarounds_", can you clarify why you call them a workaround? They pretty clearly do what you want, which is to get the `Class` object for your inner class, they may or may not be the "fastest" way but they do meet the primary requirement. Personally I don't see the point of figuring out the most performant approach given you're already using reflection.

Comment: If there's an existing duplicate, I recommend adding a bounty asking which solution is faster and if there are even faster solutions. Asking an "are there other solutions and can you benchmark for me" is not really a good new question, if there are other better answers they should be added to the duplicate

Comment: @ErikA the underlying idea here is that the new question isn't really asking the same thing. The problem is trivially solved in a couple of different ways that involve *extending* known techniques for *related* problems in trivial ways (e.g. iterate over an output array and check whether any given element meets the desired criteria), but the question is whether there is a *direct* way to solve the problem without needing to break it down into e.g. the collect-and-iterate steps. (As far as I can tell, the answer is "no".)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, that is the correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: I suspect that, as suggested on the original question, you have an XY problem.

Comment: @SecurityHound Check the delete reasons for "dead" questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions and I give you the info that the question has 2 downvotes (the only votes it has), which were cast after it got undeleted by OP.

Comment: @tgdavies By that you mean, whatever reason I originally had for querying an inner class from a class object by name, there's probably a better way of doing that entirely.

Comment: Yes, I think there probably is.

Comment: @RyanM "fastest" could also mean the least code required to achieve the desired outcome... At least that's what I took it for, initially

Comment: @Cuzy That would be 'shortest' or 'smallest.'